# $watch on clientWidth isn't working

Tags: angularjs

Inside of my directive I have this and it works only in the beginning, and whenever I resize later it never fires.

```
    scope.$watch ->
        cw: element[0].clientWidth
    ,(newValue, oldValue)->
        if newValue.cw isnt oldValue.cw
            console.log "changed"
    ,true
```

Comment: Watches are only checked on a `$digest` cycle.  If you resize the element then make another change to your scope does your code run?  You should probably create a directive for resizing that will call your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks right to me, but it's important to note that it **won't** fire on resize unless you manually trigger a digest on the resize event.

Without this, angular doesn't realise there's been an event that should trigger a digest, and so none happen.

Try adding this (remember to inject `$window`):

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', ()->
  scope.$apply();
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like Jason Goemaat said, its because Watches are only checked on a `$digest` cycle
Depending on how the way your element is resized maybe this example may help you.
Here is a menu that expands it self when pressed on the arrow.

```
<div class="menu" ng-class="{'expanded' : main.expanded}">
    <div class="menu-handler" ng-click="main.expanded = !main.expanded">
    </div>
</div>
```

The menu is expanded by a ng-click that makes a change on the scope, in this case its a boolean var that acts as a flag. As the opening of the menu is made throught the change in the scope it calls the `$digest` cycle iterating through all `$watch`.

```
scope.$watch(function() {
      return element[0].clientWidth;
}, function(oldValue, newValue) {
      console.log(oldValue, newValue);
});
```

You can view the full example in this JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/owenbcal/zf17s0mL/
Hope i was helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

the way I know about watching this kind of values is making a function that is fired once the value changes so then I watch that function :

in the service:

```
this.getDataOut = function () {
    return self.dataOut;
};
```

in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch(dataService.getDataOut, function() {
    $scope.dataOut = dataService.dataOut; 
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what he's done in the question except he's defined the function inline.